# horizontal alignment of dot over hat over bold greek letter!

Tags: horizontal-alignment, bold, greek

For some strange reason, this:

```
\hat{\dot{\bm{\phi}}}
```

prints the dot and the hat slightly off the left of the phi letter. Any ideas if this can be fixed? thanks.
Using bm package for bold symbols.

Comment: @sfrancky: if you don't mind having the accent bold, you can simply do `\bm{{\hat{\dot{\phi}}}}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$\mkern4mu\hat{\mkern-4mu\dot{\bm{\phi}}}$

$\skew{3}{\hat}{\skew{3}{\dot}{\bm{\phi}}}$
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! i was hoping for a somewhat more "official" solution, though..also, this aligns only the dot, not the hat!

Comment: you can use `\skew`, but it needs also a manual setting

Comment: it's great!! I made a new command in my preamble so that i don't need to type it every time! thanks very much!

Comment: @sfranky: In the first version, `\mkern4mu` should be inserted before the `\hat` (which I just did). @Herbert: I took the freedom to make this change. Hope you agree.

Answer (score 10):

As to *why* this happens: TeX handles accents over single characters differently, using the `\skewchar` of the font. Thus you get nicely aligned math accents only over single characters, and `\dot{\bm{\phi}}` is already a composed symbol.

If you want double accents, you can use the `amsmath` or the `accents` package. However, both packages don't work together well with `bm`, so the simple `\hat{\dot{\bm{\phi}}}` won't work with `\usepackage{accents}`. It took me forever to find out what happens, but here's a fix:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{bm,accents}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\accbm[1]{\use@mathgroup{\M@OMS}{5}{\bm{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\hat{\dot{\accbm{\phi}}}$
\end{document}
```

This gives you [image]. Thus, whenever you want to put accents over `\bm`ed characters, you just have to use `\accbm`. I should add a few words of caution: 1. It works with `\M@OMS`, but I don't know if it's the Right Way. 2. In this example, it works with font family `5` in the `\use@mathgroup`, but I don't know if it'll always work with `5`.

**UPDATE:** Philippe Goutet's great answer to my question
 [How do I identify the encoding and family of a new math font?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9296/how-do-i-identify-the-encoding-and-family-of-a-new-math-font/10642#10642) provides a solution that determines the font family automatically.

Comment: thanks for this, it's really useful, I ll embed it. Your words of caution though, I don't have the slightest idea what you are talking about :(

Comment: @sfranky: It's not necessary that you understand them; just keep in mind that it _might_ not always work. (I don't fully understand the solution myself.) If it doesn't work in your file, please tell me!

Answer (score 6):

[image]

It's easier to get accent positioning right if the accents are bold as well as the base.
Also if `\bm` does get confused by its argument adding an extra set of `{}` stops it trying to disassemble the math construct and instead it sets the entire argumant as a sing;e expression (using `\boldmath`, essentially) this is a lot simpler (but slower).
Note the extra set of braces, and the better accent positioning in row 9.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{bm}


\begin{document}

1 $\mathcal{A} \bm{\mathcal{A}}$

2 $\hat{\mathcal{A}} \bm{\hat{\mathcal{A}}}$

3 $\mathcal{\hat{A}} \bm{\mathcal{\hat{A}}}$

4 $\hat{\hat{\mathcal{A}}} \bm{\hat{\hat{\mathcal{A}}}}$

5 $\mathcal{\hat{\hat{A}}} \bm{\mathcal{\hat{\hat{A}}}}$

6 $\phi \bm{\phi}$

7 $\hat{\phi} \bm{\hat{\phi}}$

8 $\hat{\hat{\phi}} \bm{\hat{\hat{\phi}}}$

9 $\hat{\hat{\phi}} \bm{{\hat{\hat{\phi}}}}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice and simple, greatly appreciated!