# When using a dot to denote a time derivative, should the dot be centred horizontally?

Tags: amsmath, physics

When I write something like `\dot{\mathbf{J}}=\mathbf{r}\times -\frac{k}{r ^3} \mathbf{r}`, it renders as

[image]

This looks alright, but the dot above the $J$ looks slightly too far to the left. I would have thought the dot should be horizontally centred, so as to be half-way along the horizontal bar at the top of the $J$.

So, should it be centred, and if so, how do I do this?

Comment: `\skew{2}\dot{\mathbf{J}}` or some number giving a result you like. BTW the formula doesn't look right...

Comment: The dot is centered over the J if you include the whole letter.  OTOH, without \mathbf the dot is much firther to the right.

Comment: @campa Thanks for the suggestion. As for the "formula", it's not supposed to be true for a general force. I'm using the potential $V=k/r$ where $r=|\mathbf{r}|=(x^2+y^2+z²)^{1/2}$. (And I'm taking mass to be constant.)

Comment: You can solve with this link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315181/dot-over-a-not-in-the-right-place

Comment: I was referring to the minus sign after the cross product without parentheses

Comment: It seems a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/457983/dot-with-only-operator-overline

Comment: @Sebastiano Yes and no. In your question the overline was the issue, here it's different. (Oh boy, I wrote a bad answer there `:-)`.)

Comment: @campa Now change it 

Comment: @campa Wdym? Afaik, if you have vectors $u,v$ and a scalar $\sigma$, then $(\sigma u)\times v=u\times (\sigma v)=\sigma(u\times v)$, so it doesn't matter where the brackets go.

Comment: Yes, but not with a minus. It should be `\vec{r} \times (- ...)`, not `\vec{r} \times - ...`

Comment: @campa I'm quite confused. What difference does it make? I'm not aware of there being any other interpretation of what I've written. (I assume you mean it's a mathematical error and not a typesetting error.)

Answer (score 3):

(I could swear this is a duplicate but I can't find it...)

TeX tries its best to place math accents but sometimes it's not perfect. That's where the macro `\skew` comes in handy: the first argument in a number (in math units), the second is a math accent:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\dot{\mathbf{J}}$
$\skew{2.5}\dot{\mathbf{J}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the \skew

Comment: This is useful. Is there anyway of doing this automatically? As in, whether you choose 2.5 or 3 is up to the user, but maybe there is some package that determines the best spacing.